# How to do string manipulation in an NSValueTransformer?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, string

I have a table column that I'm binding to a value in an `NSArrayController`.  What I'm trying to do is display only a substring of the actual value in the array controller.  The way I've been trying to do that so far is by creating an `NSValueTransformer` subclass, and then doing the string manipulation in the `transformedValue` method.  However, I can't figure out how to get the incoming value turned into a string (it's of type `NSConcreteValue`), and maybe there's an easier way to do this without value transformers.

Comment: NSConcreteValue is a subclass of NSValue. Does the binding display the full string correctly without the transformer?

Comment: Yes - the string is being displayed fine without the transformer.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're doing presentation-side formatting, in which case you should be using a formatter instead.

Then again, if this is a string containing multiple values (e.g., something like “from 42 to 100”), you should make a model object from it instead, and store those in the array controller. Then you can bind your table columns to specific properties of the model objects, and not have to worry about picking the string apart and then reassembling it (except when you load and later save the model).

Edit: Never mind; I didn't see that the object values are NSValues, not NSStrings.

Comment: This is a long string, and I only want the first 10 or so characters to display in the table.  Is using a formatter something I can do from the bindings inspector in Interface Builder?

Comment: It's not a binding option; it's an outlet in the cell. You create the formatter in your nib, and connect the cell's formatter outlet to the formatter object.

Comment: Agreed. What you want to subclass here is NSFormatter. You just need to implement -stringForObjectValue:, and you'll probably be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a string representation of any object using the `-description` method, but for instances of NSValue it's unlikely to print anything especially meaningful. In other words, it's up to your value transformer to interpret the passed-in object and produce a string. If it's an NSValue instance, the question is what type of data that instance contains. Once you know that, you can write code to represent it as a string (similar to `NSStringFromRect()`).